# How to Gradually Increase a Number from 0 to 60 as One GameObject gets closer to another GameObject object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Have Script which calculates the distance with Vector3.Distence.

what i want is to increase a Number from 0 to 60 based on how close one gameobject is to the other gameobject. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `Mathf.Lerp()`.  Job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic maths:

```
Number = 60/(1+Distance);
```

When distance is infinity, it returns 0.
When distance is 0, it returns 60.

Edit (with comment informations):

```
Number = 15*(4-Min(4, Distance));
```

When distance is greater than 4, it returns 0.
When distance is 0, it returns 60.

Comment: OP wanted the value to _"gradually increase"_, yours is an _inverse-proportional_ function where `Number` will result in a _single digit_ for any distance in the range `{6...60}`.  It's not until `Distance = 5` will `Number` suddenly jump to two digits (10); 4 = 12; 3 = 15; 2 = 20; 1 = 30; 0 = 60.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What to do if the number should start increasing from 0 when the distance between gameobjects is less than 4 and when the distance between the gameobjects is 0 it should reach 60?

Comment: @MickyD OP didn't ask for natural numbers. And there is no definition for *gradually increase*, my response obviously use reel numbers and the function is continuous (gradual?) and increase when the objects get closer. In other words, garbage in, garbage out. This is a really poor quality question and doesn't deserve more.